# Troubles with bootstrap glyphicons on the ipad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, mobile-safari, glyphicons

I am trying to display a datetimepicker with the calendar glyphicon. This is the HTML:

```
  <div class='input-group date' id='fuel-start-datetimepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" id="fuel-start-input" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
   </div>
```

When viewing this on an iPad in Safari, the calendar icon shows up as an emoji monkey. I am baffled because I can change the icon to a different glyphicon (tried it with the star) and it shows up fine. Also this works fine on the iPad by itself:

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

I am not sure how that is at all different than what I have - it's the same markup. Very confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "this works fine on the iPad by itself"? Its possible that the HTML character: e109 is being used by the Emoji keyboard as the monkey too as is being overridden. Try using different glyphicons. Go to the getbootstrap page and look at the glyphs on the iPad and see if they look normal or are overridden too.

Comment: I mean I put it in a js fiddle with just that one line with the span and the calendar shows up as expected on the ipad.

Comment: Thats strange. Are you running this HTML on the IOS device locally or is it on a website that you are accessing via the IOS device?

Comment: Try this technique: https://litmus.com/community/code/758-stop-ios-converting-html-entity-unicode-to-emoji you will need to use the `\e109` character though instead of the one that is in the example.

Comment: It's on a website that I'm accessing. I also just looked at Bootstrap's page with all the glyphicons and they are all displaying properly, it seems that only the calendar on my site is rendering as an emoji.

Comment: You are not alone. I am using a magnifier icon in a search button and it shows up as a 'kiss' emoji .. trying to find out what happens..

Comment: i have the monkey on my local application on the ipad too. On the browser i see '+'

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. I downloaded the latest bootstrap version and replaced the "glyphicons-halflings-regular.*" files. It solved my "monkey emoji" problem.

Comment: What version of the files did you download that fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In glyphicons.css

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

src: url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

Change to ./assets/ => this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Today my co-founder alerted the rest of the development team that she saw a monkey emoji on our production web app. It was pretty late in the day and we were all pretty exhausted from an iOS app update we were pushing (not to mention nobody had touched the web app code in weeks) so we were all heavily inclined to believe she had completely lost her mind.

Nevertheless, we spent 40 minutes trying to reproduce it on her and our iPhones. We opened the page in private browsing mode, turned on/off WiFi, visited the pages she had visited before our page in case some sort of memory was leaking between tabs. Nothing. Clearly, this was all monkey business.

But it kept bugging me. So I decided to try one last thing. As part of our iOS app update, we had been using our app under really poor network conditions using the [Network Link Conditioner](https://www.natashatherobot.com/simulate-bad-network-ios-simulator/). Her phone was one of the test devices we had used, so I checked her settings and saw that somebody had forgotten to turn it off. I decided to try switching the speed from 3G down to Edge. I reloaded the page and there he was.

Where our `glyphicon-calendar` once was.

was staring back at me.